# "Killed" trying to use save_mfdataset()

Tags: dask, python-xarray

I have a dask dataset (~200GB on disk) upon which I perform some calculations (masking and adding up sea ice extent). I am trying to write out this dask dataset:

```
ds_mod_trim = <xarray.DataArray (ensemble: 12, init_time: 408, fore_time: 1367)>
dask.array<shape=(12, 408, 1367), dtype=float64, chunksize=(12, 408, 40)>
Coordinates:
  * init_time  (init_time) datetime64[ns] 1980-01-01 1980-02-01 1980-03-01 ...
  * ensemble   (ensemble) int64 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
  * fore_time  (fore_time) timedelta64[ns] 0 days 29 days 30 days 31 days ...
```

to multiple netcdf files like this:

```
c_e, datasets = zip(*ds_mod_trim.to_dataset(name='sic').groupby('ensemble'))
paths = ['GFDL_extent_esns_%s.nc' % e for e in c_e]
xr.save_mfdataset(datasets, paths)
```

Where:

```
datasets[0] = <xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (fore_time: 1367, init_time: 408)
Coordinates:
  * init_time  (init_time) datetime64[ns] 1980-01-01 1980-02-01 1980-03-01 ...
    ensemble   int64 1
  * fore_time  (fore_time) timedelta64[ns] 0 days 29 days 30 days 31 days ...
Data variables:
    sic        (init_time, fore_time) float64 dask.array<shape=(408, 1367), chunksize=(408, 40)>
```

Which produces a "Killed". When I watch the memory usage, it stays around 85-90%, but the CPU usage jumps up from 100% to ~650% before the system freezes up and I get the "Killed".

When I check the directory, the files have been created with correct dimensions/coords, but missing the correct variable (no data).

I expected save_mfdataset() to handle this use case? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: can you also show what `datasets[0]` looks like before saving? This is something that we should expect to work though the integration with dask is not bulletproof at the moment.

Comment: @jhamman added datasets[0] output. I also tried grouping by in a few different ways (i.e. to have groups of smaller memory, but no change).